# How to get rid of C4800 warning produced by boost::flyweight in VS2008

Tags: c++, mfc, boost, compiler-warnings

I get a warning when compiling below code in VS2008 with MFC turned on. Boost version 1.39

```
include "boost/flyweight.hpp"
include "boost/flyweight/key_value.hpp"
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo(const CString& item) : mfoo(item) {}
    const CString& getkeyvalue() const {return mfoo;}
  private:
    const CString mfoo;
};
struct Conversion
{
  const CString& operator() (const Foo& item) const {return item.getkeyvalue();}
};  

using namespace boost::flyweights;
flyweight<key_value<CString, Foo, Conversion>, tag<Foo> > flyweight_test;
```

The last line in the above code produces a warning

d:\work\sourcecode\boost1390\boost\functional\hash\extensions.hpp(72) : warning C4800: `'const wchar_t *'` : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
d:\work\sourcecode\boost1390\boost\functional\hash\extensions.hpp(71) : while compiling class template member function `size_t boost::hash<T>::operator ()(const T &) const` with
       [
          `T=ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t>>`
       ]
d:\work\sourcecode\boost1390\boost\multi_index\hashedindex.hpp(1159) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::hash<T>' being compiled with
       [
          `T=ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t>>`
       ]

This warning goes on and on, through hashed factory, MPL, etc.

Why is the warning there and how do I correct the code so no warning is produced?

Edit:
To fix, add below implementation of hash_value

```
template<typename CharType, typename TraitsType>
std::size_t hash_value(const ATL::CStringT<CharType, TraitsType>& s)
{
    return CStringElementTraits<typename TraitsType>::Hash(s);
}
```

Comment: I had a similar warning once in my code. There it happened when I tried to call a templated function with a const char* (or const wchar_t* in your case) and multiple overloads were available. I wanted the implicit conversion to string, but the compiler picked up the conversion to bool.

Comment: I wonder if it would have helped to compile with GCC, which I recall being pretty explicit about where problems come from? Or is that completely infeasible with MFC? Or does GCC not give this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the classes in flyweight probably uses the hash_value functions (or the wrapper class hash) to calculate a hash value from a ATL::CString. This is not defined in boost directly, so you'll need to provide an implementation:

```
std::size_t hash_value(const ATL::CString& s)
{
     // ...
}
```

Just looking at your compiler output, it seems that CString itself is templated, so you would implement

```
template<typename CharType, typename TraitsType>
std::size_t hash_value(const ATL::CString<CharType, TraitsType>& s)
{
     // calculate hash e.g. by calling hash_value(const std::string&)
}
```

Comment: Great lead. Indeed, the hash_value was being generated based on bool. Totally incorrect in this case. Implementation provided in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

I compile with /Wall which causes Boost to generate all sorts of warnings. Furthermore, I instruct the compiler to treat all warnings as errors, so it becomes necessary to have no warnings at all.

In order to avoid getting any warnings while compiling the Boost headers, I use #pragma warning to temporarily lower the warning level as low as possible and turn off any remaining warnings while processing the Boost headers:

```
// set minimal warning level
#pragma warning(push,0)
// some warnings still occur at this level
// if necessary, disable specific warnings not covered by previous pragma
#pragma warning(disable:4800)

#include 

// restore warning level
#pragma warning(pop)
```

This makes sure my code is compiled with the highest level of error checking possible while code the I have no control over can still compile successfully.

The only other options I can see are to ignore the warnings or maintain a patched version of the Boost code until those warnings are fixed, neither of which is very appealing.

Comment: I'm not really looking to disable the warning. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The C4800 warning is emitted by the compiler, when it must convert a int expression to a bool.

E.g. :

```
int k = 11;
bool f()
{ return k; }
```

The int expression k, is transformed from the internal definition of

```
k == 0 => *false*
k != 0 => *true*
```

to the *bool* Definition of

```
b == false (internally == 0) => *false*
b == true  (internally == 1) => *true*
```

Because any value (other then 0) may represent *true* in C++, the compiler has to convert k into a bool.

As the warning rightfully states, this conversion might present a performance hit.

NB: This warning may be a bit superfluous, because the compiler normally extracts the right meaning from the code, and optimizes this away.

Pseudo C code which the compiler would create from my sample code :

```
char f()
{
    if( k )
       return (char) 1;
    return (char) 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for an explanation about how bad C4800 was, but haven't found anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to correct that warning but you can turn it off by adding the code below to your cpp file:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4800)
```

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(VS.80).aspx) for further reference.

Comment: Not looking to disable warning. This is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the warning is not in your code. You'd have to fix the offending Boost code.

Comment: Not helpful. With templates, whilst it can be the expanded code that gives the compile warning/error, the root cause can be in the application code